# Web Scraping - How to scrape when markup is different?

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to write a script that will scrape data from university websites and was wondering how scraping is possible when HTML might vary from site to site. Do we need to add some kind of intelligence for it to identify and scape from several sites?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at building a web scraping framework to scrape recipe websites in general and it sounds like what you are trying to do is similar although there may be more structure in the way the Universities represent the data.

What you want to look for across the websites is similar features around the information you want. It is hard to give specific advice without knowing the information that you want to gather but if you want to scrape for term dates for example then you will be looking for text in the page that looks like a date with some text on the page, preferably inside some sort of header tag that has text such as 'Term dates'.

Making a program that can manage on a range of sites will be difficult and depending in the number and frequency you want to scrape it might just be better to make a framework for yourself where you can swap in new css selectors for each new site.

To make something fully automated you would probably want to create some kind of machine learning model. The plan that I had for the recipe sites was to use linear regression to give a value to the probability an element was the element the algorithm was searching for based on a set of features. So for example the recipe title is likely to be the largest header tag on the page. The bigger the header tag the higher the probability the tag contains the recipe title. This is not always the case though and often the largest header tag will be the name of the blog and so to combat that the algorithm would need to look at how the largest header tag's condense changed over the pages on that domain.
To train the regression model you would need a dataset containing examples where you had manually labeled the elements on the page.

I decided in the end that it was easier to simply build a framework where I could check for the CSS selector of each element I wanted and let the algorithm run across the site using those.

Comment: Thanks. I too finally did the same. However, the model you are saying might really solve this. I will give it a try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DhanushuUzumaki I would apreciate if this answer helped you, if you could mark it as the chosen answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide additional details. There are many frameworks available for parsing html e.g. [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), [Cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/), etc...and different approaches for retrieving the data such [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and XPath.